# can't access the pages without using frontend_dev.php

Tags: symfony-1.4

I have a project that Im able to access using the url like this:

http://127.0.0.1:9898/frontend_dev.php

When I try to access the same url without frontend_dev.php just like: http://127.0.0.1:9898 I can see the main view but the links inside I get **Not found error**.

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasnt the project configuration. I didnt have the apache's mod_rewrite available:

To enable mod_rewrite:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

and then

Reload all apache config files:

```
service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Please check your .htaccess file in rood directory of your project.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
  # getting no_script_name to work
  #RewriteBase /

  # we skip all files with .something
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  #RewriteRule .* - [L]

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^favicon\.ico
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

2)  Do you able to get access using the url like this?

h ttp://127.0.0.1:9898/index.php

Comment: THanks for your reply. I already find the solution for this problem. I'm working with ubuntu and I didn't have the apache's mod_rewrite available.